# How do you catch a managed exception (from a delegate) in unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, .net, exception, delegates, managed-c++

I have unmanaged C++ calling a managed delegate via the function pointer provided by Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate.  This delegate has the potential to throw an exception.  I need to be able to properly handle this exception in my unmanaged C++ to ensure things like pointer cleanup, and potentially rethrow the exception up into more managed code.  The call stack is similar to this:

Managed Code -> Unmanaged C++ -> callback to Managed Code via delegate (exception can be thrown here).

Anyone have pointers for properly handling this situation so that the resources in unmanaged code can be cleaned up and a usable exception can be thrown out to the managed code which initiated the whole call stack?

Answer (score 2):

Catching from managed code with

```
try
{
  throw gcnew InvalidOperationException();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException^ e)
{
  // Process e
  throw;
}
```

And an

```
[assembly:RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)];
```

on your assembly catches managed and unmanaged exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Don't even remotely try to make the "unmanaged" code aware of the fact that it will have to deal with .NET.

Return a non-zero value from your callback to signal the presence of an error. Provide a (thread local) global string object describing the error so that you can retrieve a helpful error message for the user.

This may involve wrapping your delegate into another function under the scenes, which will catch all the exceptions and return the error code.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use SEH, and do the cleanup in the exception filter before continuing the exception propagation. But I'm not sure that is overly legal since you would be doing a lot of work in the filter.  You also wouldn't know anything about the managed exception being propagated.

An alternative is to wrap the managed delegate with your own managed function that catches the exception and in turn throws an unmanaged exception ... which you can then catch in your unmanaged code.

When the unmanaged code has done its cleanup use another helper managed function to re-throw the original managed exception

Answer (score 0):

Managed code represents exceptions as hardware exceptions, unlike C++. You could use SEH. Remember that you always get the chance to run the exception filter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

I was told...{the vector  can't show if variables a&b weren't declared in the scope process.  After a bit of digging figured out that the loop hole was as follows--- weibull_distribution> unmanaged_code